# SSL защита соеденения

Tags: windows, ssl, auth, ldap

Имеется некая API.

Имеется некое кол-во юзеров с софтом. (OS win и там и там)

Софт делает запрос к API с помощью курла(CURLAUTH_NTLM) передавая туда ':' (credentials вообщем, не знаю как по русски)

Безопасно ли это? могу ли я перехватить данные запроса и подделать его?
Спасет ли SSL и как им правильно пользоваться, мне нужно полностью доверять юзеру который делает запрос и проверять его.